# How do you loop all columns names in a trigger without hard coding them

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger, create-table

I want to create a trigger (insert / update) that checks if all column values (except those in the primary key) in a record are null. The number of columns can change so i wish to 'loop' the column names rather than hard coding the columns in the trigger. Below very simplified example of my database scheme

```
CREATE TABLE `specs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `spec1` enum('yes','no') DEFAULT NULL,
  `spec2` enum('yes','no') DEFAULT NULL,
  `spec3` enum('yes','no') DEFAULT NULL,
  `spec4` enum('yes','no') DEFAULT NULL,
  `spec5` enum('yes','no') DEFAULT NULL,
  /* ... can be any number of columns */
  `rowEmpty` enum('yes','no') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


insert into specs (`id`,`spec1`,`spec2`,`spec3`,`spec4`,`spec5`)
VALUES (1,null,'yes',null,null,null),(2,null,null,'no',null,null),(3,'yes','no',null,null,null),(4,null,null,null,null,null),(5,null,'yes',null,'yes','yes'),(6,null,null,null,'no',null),(7,null,null,null,null,null);

Update specs set `spec1` = 'yes' where id = 7
```

The insert and update triggers should set the column rowEmpty to 'yes' for record ID 4. For all other records rowEmpty should be 'no'.

How do i loop to all columns names in a trigger without hard coding them?

Comment: 'How do i loop to all columns names in a trigger without hard coding them' normally the answer to this would be to build a sql statement from information_schema,columns and call dynamic sql BUT you cannot call dynamic sql from a trigger,,

Comment: What P.Salmon said (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-prepared-statements.html), and whenever you have a table design with multiple columns having the same name and an increasing integer it screams "bad schema design". Consider having those as rows, not as columns.

Comment: @Nebu . . . "The number of columns can change."  There is something wrong with your data model.  You are storing values in columns that should be in separate rows.

Comment: I don't believe that you can do it, to get dynamic columns you need INFORMATION_SCHEMA or dynamic sql and both can't be used in trigger. Do the updating from your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use a generated column for that?

Of course, that *still* requires you to enumerate all the columns, but just once, and directly in the table definition (where, obviously, column names are available). And that saves you the effort of creating a trigger for each and every DML operation:

```
create table specs (
        id int(11) not null,
        spec1 enum('yes','no') default null,
        spec2 enum('yes','no') default null,
        spec3 enum('yes','no') default null,
        spec4 enum('yes','no') default null,
        spec5 enum('yes','no') default null,
        rowempty enum('yes','no') as (
            case when coalesce(spec1, spec2, spec3, spec4, spec5) is null
            then 'yes'
            else 'no'
        end),
        primary key (id)
) engine=innodb default charset=utf8;
```

Comment: 'The number of columns can change' - I assumed the OP meant that there can be more or less at any given point in time.

Comment: Doh didn't thought of this. I only need to recreate the generated column when a column is dropped or added but this is not a problem. @P.Salmon this will work in my scenario, but my question could have been more clear.